# Book review for "Qualitative Mathematics for the Social Sciences"

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, mathematical-psychology

Has anyone read/reviewed this book - [Qualitative Mathematics for the Social Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415444829)? I have been trying to find a credible review on the reliability of the book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Meta opinion seemed to lean slightly (-1) against book reviews being within scope. http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/956/2868